# Allowing embedding of HTML to other pages. Iframe-, Script-tag?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embedded-resource

I need to allow other people to embed some of my HTML and Javascript code. The HTML code itself is too much to be copy&pasted.

Should I use Iframes or script-tags for embeding it?

The script tags and iframes are used for example by Stackoverflow on [Flair page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair)
How does those even exactly work? Aren't those a security risk?

What method would you prefer?

Comment: iframes and script tags _should_ serve entirely different purposes - what *exactly* are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Make a file such as content.html and paste the html source there. Then you can include this file in the place you want to appear. For example, using php you can use

```
include 'path/to/content.html';
```

at the place you want to embed the html

Comment: Hups, I think my question was a bit unclear. I need to allow other people to embed my content.